# Associate a viewer to an existing window under PCL

Tags: c++, windows, point-cloud-library

I am using PCL to display a point cloud under Windows. The CloudViewer and PCLVisualizer classes are available for this purpose. But when you instantiate them, they create their own window (via VTK). As I want to integrate the display window in a complete GUI, I am looking for a way to direct the display to an existing window, possibly by passing the window handle. The window is not OpenGL.

Is that possible ? Any hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I have found a solution.

Several Web posts suggest to change the parent window of the RenderWindow of the viewer, which can be done with

```
viewer->getRenderWindow()->SetParentId(hWnd);
```

Anyway, this doesn't seem to have an effect. But it inspired me to reparent using the Windows function instead,

```
SetParent((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), hWnd);
```

This indeed makes the viewer a child of my window, while it continues to work correctly. Additional style flags can be adjusted with `SetWindowLong`.

For now I have also kept the first statement, just in case. It doesn't seem to bother.