# Integrating PCL Visualizer in MFC/win32 window

Tags: c++, mfc, vtk, win32gui, pcl

I am trying to use the PCL Visializer as it is inside an MFC CStatic control :

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr simpleVis(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud , HWND hParent_display )
{
    // --------------------------------------------
    // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
    // --------------------------------------------
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D Viewer"));
    
    if (hParent_display) {
        
        SetParent((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), hParent_display);

        viewer->setWindowBorders(false);
        viewer->getRenderWindow()->SetParentId(hParent_display);

        //viewer->setPosition(-10, -50);  // Hacky way to hide the window borders

        viewer->setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0);
        viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud, "sample cloud");
        viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "sample cloud");
        viewer->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
        viewer->initCameraParameters();

    }

    return (viewer);
}
```

I call the above function in MFC `OnInitDialog()` like this :

```
viewer = simpleVis(basic_cloud_ptr , GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_3D_VIWER)->m_hWnd);
```

and this is the result :

[image]

As you can see the child window title bar is visible and the user can move it using a mouse.

[image]

`viewer->setWindowBorders(false);` didn't work.
Using `viewer->setPosition(-10, -50);`   hides the title bar but I am not sure if this is the proper way to achieve that.

[image]

Is there a better way to integrate the Visualizer?

Update :

This is what worked :

```
pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr simpleVis(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr cloud , HWND hParent_display ,int width , int height)
{
    // --------------------------------------------
    // -----Open 3D viewer and add point cloud-----
    // --------------------------------------------

    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("3D Viewer"));
    
    if (hParent_display) {
        
        viewer->setWindowBorders(false);
        //viewer->getRenderWindow()->SetParentId(hParent_display);

        SetParent((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), hParent_display);
        
        SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
        SetWindowPos((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        ShowWindow((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), SW_SHOW);

        viewer->setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0);
        //viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud, "sample cloud");
        //viewer->setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "sample cloud");
        viewer->addCoordinateSystem(1.0);
        viewer->initCameraParameters();

    }

    return (viewer);
}
```

Comment: This is the effect you get when you reparent a window that isn't a child window (i.e., one that has the `WS_CHILD` window style set). One would expect that `SetParentId()` does everything that's needed, but [apparently it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39244430).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your `viewer->setWindowBorders(false);` does.

I would use plain Win32 API to remove the title bar.

Please note that you would need to redraw that window frame after the style is modified:

```
 SetWindowPos(hwnd,0,0,0,0,0,SWP_DRAWFRAME|SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```

Comment: Do you mean removing the title bar of the parent window or the PCL child window ? (the child window is of type pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::Ptr )

Comment: @Ziri I mean the one with the `3D Viewer` title.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and this is what worked : SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
SetWindowPos((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, width, height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
ShowWindow((HWND)viewer->getRenderWindow()->GetGenericWindowId(), SW_SHOW);

Comment: @Ziri That's not actually what you want. You want a **child** window, so remove the `WS_POPUP` style and set the `WS_CHILD` style. You no longer need `HWND_TOPMOST`, and the child window automatically moves along with its parent in the Z-order.